# Word or phrase for a sale or transfer between two divisions or branches of the same company

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, business-language

I want a word or word phrase like 'Sales and Customer Service', but it applies only to the sale or transfer of stock between branches or divisions of the same company.

It's for internal transactions only, but it's still more than a simple stock transfer.

I'm thinking I could simply use the phrase 'Transfer Sales' because to me that describes exactly what I'm trying to say, but I don't know if this makes sense to other people or already means something else.

Comment: Just curious. How is it different from Inter-Departmental Transfers (IDT)?

Comment: You’d be best off asking the finance guys at your company what they call it.

Comment: Are you thinking of a situation where the supplying division or department gives advice on the product to be transferred and then supports the receiving department support in using or maintaining it? If so I can see why it's more than a simple transfer. I suggest you could use "Internal account management"

Comment: Thanks @BoldBen that is exactly what I was trying to explain.

Comment: I'd reiterate @Jim s suggestion to consult finance guys as, there can be crazy tax and financial reporting ramifications in terms of how these things get classified, and consistency within an organization is really key.  There are times where even a "sale" might want to be emphasized - 'internal sale' .  Will the goods be tranfered on internal balance sheets at purchase cost ? will there be load factors applied ? do the divisions maintain separate cash accounts or are they consolidated.  Is there an agreed on price vs carrying value?

Comment: I would call it a *shuffle*.

Comment: By "stock" do you mean certificates of ownership, office supplies, manufactured products, or materials to be  used in manufacturing?

Comment: Different companies account for it in different ways; you need to find out. Some may treat it the same way as an external purchase/sale, others may have a special procedure, or (in a small company) no procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Intra Company Transactions? Or Intra Organizational Transfers. I use the word 'intra' because it implies interactions between multiple sections of the same whole.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of a type of transaction that would be described as a [Related Party Transaction](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/related-partytransaction.asp)?

> **Related Parties:**
>   Related parties and business services can take many different forms. Some of the most common types of related parties include business affiliates, shareholder groups, subsidiaries, and minority-owned companies. Related party transactions can include sales, leases, service agreements, and loan agreements.

The quoted Investopedia article expands on some of the points in @Tom22's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to upgrade my comment to an answer as it seems more complete than some of the given answers and none of them has been accepted yet.

The question relates to transfers of goods from one part of the organisation to another with the type of advice on the product to obtain and ongoing support for its usage which are called "pre and post sales support" when applied to external sales. This is often called Account Management in the external sale context.

Given this I suggest that the term **Internal Account Management** would describe what's being done within the organisation.